# Shorting the Shenzen or ChiNext Index

Tags: etf, shorting-securities

is there any possibility to short the Shenzhen or ChiNext Index as an individual Investor? It seems as there are no options but two ETFs, namely the CSOP SZSE CHINEXT ETF-HKD and the ChinaAMC SME-ChiNext ETF. How would I be able to short these?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I am living in Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a global perspective there is the FTSE China 50 A shares index. So this index is the basis for futures contracts around the globe, and ETFs and other funds.

In the United States there is the YINN and YANG. These are both 3x bull/bear FTSE China A shares ETFs with options!!!!!! Isn't that amazing? The contracts are not liquid but you can get filled and with the expected volatility of that index, the spread is basically irrelevant! So nuts

Comment: But there are no options on the Shenzhen or ChiNext Index right?

Comment: I just found http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/market/partcir/sehk/2015/Documents/CT03415E.pdf, saying the ETF is eligible for short selling. But where is an individual able to short this?

Comment: @Alex on the Hong Kong Stock Exchange.

Comment: Would there be a difference between YINN Puts and YANG Calls?

Comment: The regular YANG looks the most promising I think. Problem with the options is, that the longest ones already expire in Jan 2016. Another interesting Index would be the CSI 500. Are you aware of any ETFs or options on that?

Comment: @Alex when do you expect the crash to occur? Also, leveraged ETFs decay in value over time, in any market. 6 months+ in a leveraged ETF trying to go against the market trend is insanity as is, and you want longer term options on top of that which come with their own theta decay? It is fairly easy to get extra options series listed on any optionable exchange traded product, in the united states

Comment: My opinion is that a valuation like that of the ChiNext or Shenzhen Index is insane and not sustainable and that a major crash will be coming in the next 3 years or so.  Since I am looking for something with an explosive upside, a long term option (preferably out of the money) for at least 1.5 years but as long as possible, may be suitable. If it turns out that there are no options available or a better way on betting on that scenario I would look into other ways? How does it work to get extra options listed? Do you know if brokers like Interactive Brokers offer some service for that?

Comment: @Alex I get it and share the sentiment, but that time period is too long. Anyway, I just call or email the CBOE. You just have to make it sound like there is a market for those options, so if they ask if you are a lone retail trader, say no. Make up the name of a firm or fund you are with, if you have to. They can have stuff listed the next day.

Comment: Great idea, thanks for the advice. I will send an email to CBOE tomorrow, requesting a USD nominated put option on the CHINEXT COMPOSITE with a strike price of 2700. If you are interested in this as well I can inform you about the process.

Comment: And do I have to be a CBOE Trading Permit Holder in order to do this? At least that is what they say on their website in order to make an option listing request. Are you aware of another possibility to avoid this?

Comment: @Alex I have personally gotten additional options listed on securities by both calling and emailing. I do not have a CBOE Trading Permit and I don't know what else to tell you

Answer (score 0):

I have also done a lot of research on this and unfortunately there seems little options out there in the ETF market. I would be nice to have an inverse play on 3147.HK. There is a lot of ETF's that track the broad market and the A'list mainland shares, but nothing for these overvalued bubble shares! Anyone got any advice to get in on this shorting opportunity?

BR
Sc